# how to run react native code from server? i want to release app in android and apple store

Tags: react-native, file-upload, server

I am an android developer and learning react native.
I made an app in React Native and now I want to release my app in android play store and apple store but I don't know where do I put my react native project code/files?
I had put react native code in my PHP(Linux) server but it's not working, it says file not found 404.
please guide, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to generate build standalone signed apk.

Generating Signed APK
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

1) first create keystore file and put in android folder location

2) setting up gradle for keystore

3) run comman

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

after success run command you will file apk-release.apk in andorid/app/build/outputs/apk/ location

then you can uplaod apk to app store

Answer (score 0):

**If your app doesn't need detach** (for example doesn't use bluetooth) you can use `create-react-native-app` and put your app code inside new project. That way you can publish your app to https://expo.io/ . It's a great way to publish your app without Google Play and App Store.

1. Here is instruction for creating new  react native app with expo kit:
   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
2. And here is how to publish it into expo:
   https://docs.expo.io/versions/v25.0.0/guides/publishing.html#how-to-publish

**All you need is** `create-react-native-app` and `exp` command line tools.